# Getting trash value from array even though I initialized it

Tags: c

> "Complete the solution so that the function will break up camel
> casing, using a space between words."

I attached the error message image below. I think this is because of wrong memory access, but I did initialize the `temp` array so I thought there wouldn't be this kind of problem.
Can anyone let me know why this happened?

```
#include <stddef.h> // NULL
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//returned buffer should be dynamically allocated and will be freed by a caller
char* solution(const char *camelCase) {
  char* res;
  res = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
  
  while(*camelCase) {
    if (*camelCase >= 'A' && *camelCase <= 'Z') {
      strcat(res, " ");
      char temp[2] = {*camelCase, '\0'};
      strcat(res, temp);
    }
    else {
      char temp[2] = {*camelCase, '\0'};
      strcat(res, temp);
    }
    camelCase++;
  }
  return res;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not use images to show output. Just copy/paste the text into the question and format it as necessary.

Comment: Is `"FooBar"` meant to be broken into `"Foo Bar"` or `" Foo Bar"` (or is it an invalid input)?

Comment: Suggestion: your last 2 lines of the `if` and `else` are 100% equal. You may want to move them outside the `if` statement and 'lose' the `else`. In C99 or later, these 2 lines can be replaced with the single line `strcat(res, (char[]){*camelCase, '\0'});`

Comment: Use `calloc` instead of `malloc`. `calloc` initializes the allocated memory to zeros, while `malloc` doesn't initialize the memory returned and it may contain garbage values.

Comment: @pmg i get what you're saying. all the inputs are in camel case so i didn't consider about the case of "FooBar". and thank y'all for the tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory returned by `malloc` is uninitialized.  So when you call `strcat` on `res`, it is reading uninitialized memory looking for a terminating null byte.  This can also potentially read past the end of allocated memory.  Both can trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Add a null byte to the start of the buffer to make it an empty string.  Then you can append to it.

```
res = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
res[0] = 0;
```